# how to read space in scanset in C language

Tags: c

I am trying to understand scanset in C.

I want to input string that consist of letter A-Z ,a-z and can have spaces between it.

Example : if input is : `ABCD abcd 123`

then output should be : `ABCD abcd.`

I tried to do  this by : `scanf("%[A-ZA-Z^\n]",c)` , where `c` is char array but it doesn't read space.

Please suggest a way to do this.

Comment: try:  `scanf("%[^[0-9]\n]", str);`

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan, it catches way more than just A-z and space

Comment: @userXX You should use [fgets](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/) to avoid uninvited buffer overflow.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan :though it worked but i didn't get how.can you explain?

Comment: @user122345656  inverts `^` discards if any symbol come  that is `0` to `9` and `\n` and scanf stop scan

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't have the inversion (`^`) in the middle like that, it has to be the first character in the set, if used.

You can of course just include a space in the set:

```
scanf("%[A-Za-z ]", c);
```

should work.